# how to read the data where the celltype is the formula in Excel

Tags: java, excel

When i `System.err.println` the cell type, one of the columns cell type show in result is the formula for vlookup which i've included in excel, how can i get the cell value instead of the formula ? Please help , thanks.

Excel data : [Click here to view my current excel file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TQj6LOBAO-oYdUD5fH9WIq2KkN741JWilCJxE6M4eVM/edit#gid=2111201038)

Java code:

```
while(rowIter.hasNext())
                {
                    HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
                    Iterator cellIter = row.cellIterator();
                    Vector cellStoreVector=new Vector();

                    if(row.getRowNum()>0)
                    {             
                        for (int colnum=0; colnum<colsize; colnum++)
                        {

                            HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) row.getCell(colnum);
                            //System.err.println("colsize==="+cell);
                            if(cell == null)
                            {
                                value= "";
                            }
                            else
                            {      
                                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                    if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                                        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                                        value = dateFormat.format(cell.getDateCellValue());
                                    } 
                                    else 
                                    {
                                        double value2 = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                                        if( Math.floor(value2) == value2 ) 
                                        {
                                            int value3 = (int)value2;
                                            value = ""+value3;
                                        }else{
                                            value = String.valueOf(value2);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                    value = cell.getStringCellValue();
                                    break;
                                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:   
                                    value = "";
                                    break;                      
                                }   
                            }
                            cellStoreVector.addElement(value+"");
                        }
                        cellVectorHolder.addElement(cellStoreVector);
                    }
                }
```

result : 
colsize===null
colsize===null
colsize===null
colsize===null
colsize===null
colsize===IF(ISBLANK(E926),"",VLOOKUP(E926,BANKCODE,2,FALSE))
colsize===null

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use FormulaEvaluator as described in documents https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html

There are three method to evaluate formula with FormulaEvaluator

- evaluate formula and just return result: **evaluate(Cell cell)**
- evaluate formula and replace formula with result: **evaluateInCell(Cell cell)**
- evaluate formula and write result in cell alongside with formula: **evaluateFormulaCell(Cell cell)**

Quote from POI documentation for last option:

> Using FormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(Cell cell)
>
> evaluateFormulaCell(Cell cell) will check to see if the supplied cell is a formula cell. If it isn't, then no changes will be made to it. If it is, then the formula is evaluated. The value for the formula is saved alongside it, to be displayed in excel. The formula remains in the cell, just with a new value
>
> The return of the function is the type of the formula result, such as Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/somepath/test.xls");
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis); //or new XSSFWorkbook("/somepath/test.xls")
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
FormulaEvaluator evaluator =     wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

// suppose your formula is in B3
CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("B3"); 
Row row = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
Cell cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol()); 

if (cell!=null) {
    switch (evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell)) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
            System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
            System.out.println(cell.getErrorCellValue());
            break;

        // CELL_TYPE_FORMULA will never occur
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA: 
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: fixed: add quote from documentation